# cv::Mat of large integers

Tags: c++, opencv, integer, 8-bit

I am struggling with putting large integers, such as 2942584, in a cv Mat. The only type accepting it was CV_8UC1, but it changes the value from 2942584 to 120 (well in 8 bits obviously).

But is there anyway to have the original value in a cv Mat??

Here is the simple code if it helps:

```
Mat matrix(6,10,CV_8UC1);
matrix.at<char>(0,0) = 2942584;
cout << (int)matrix.at<char>(0,0);
```

output:

```
120
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you define matrix as `CV_8UC1` you define that every element must be 8 bit. That means that you can store only value from 0 to 255. If you want to use a big number you should define matrix as `CV_32UC1` for `unsigned integers` or `CV_32SC1` for `signed integers`. Also you should to store a value as `int` instead of `char` and read it in appropriate way.

More correct code is

```
Mat matrix(6,10,CV_32SC1); 
matrix.at<int>(0,0) = 2942584;
cout << (int)matrix.at<int>(0,0);
```

One more thing: format of the matrix element is the following

```
CV_<NUMBER_OF_BITS><SIGNED/UNSIGNED>C<NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS>
```

Comment: Okay, I had tried CV_32SC1 but indeed char was the problem. Thank you so much

Comment: @George if you use an incorrect type for matrix allocation in memory, you will have a memory leak problem in future, that will be really hard to debug.

Comment: Okay, I will make sure to watch for this in the future. Those details are so obvious that unfortunately there is not a lot written in the documentation, and I didn't manage to figure it out by myself. Thanks again for the help!